# align-items: center makes img disappear

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So with the grid, when I don't have `align-items: center;` the img shows fine, but once I add `align-items: center;` it suddenly disappears. What's causing this issue?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x1050" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid align">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x1050" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This seems to be a Chrome issue. It's also not fitting the img properly on firefox.

Comment: I'm actually seeing the exact opposite - it only shows up when `align-items` is set.

Comment: `.align` is only on the 2nd div. intentional?

Comment: @wazz It's to show the difference between the two. At least, that's my guess.

Comment: @jhpratt yep, it was to show it showing up in one and not the other

Comment: Also, the div class name in HTML is 'grid align' whereas it is just 'align' in CSS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because of the way percentage heights are rendered in the browser.

When `align-items: center` is not present, `align-items: stretch` (the default value) is in effect. This automatically gives the flex item (the `div`) full height.

But when `align-items: center` is present, it vertically centers the div. The child of the div, the `img` with `max-height: 100%`, actually computes to `height: auto`, because there is no height reference on the parent (the div flex items).

**The problem is resolved by setting a height on the flex items.**

```
.grid > div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid>div {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x1050" />
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="grid align">
  <div>
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x1050" />
  </div>
</div>
```

More details here:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

Comment: hmm, but the text no longer centers, which was my original intention of using `align-items: center`. I guess I'll just have to use position absolute on the `span` then. But this answers the question.

Comment: No need for absolute positioning. This works in Chrome and Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/yzoj5f8f/6/